# Skip items of a specific type in foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, foreach

I have this code for filling datatable from excel file:

```
for (int rowIndex = cells.FirstRowIndex; rowIndex <= cells.LastRowIndex; rowIndex++)
{
    var values = new List<string>();
    foreach (var cell in cells.GetRow(rowIndex))
    {
        values.Add(cell.Value.StringValue);
    }
    dataTable.LoadDataRow(values.ToArray(), true);
}
```

I have problem when cell is not same datatype as I set in table.

How to skip cell which is wrong datatype?

I also know this, but I can't make it work in my case:

```
foreach //...
{
    if //if datatype is not right
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use LINQ `OfType<IMyType>()` method to filter out wrong items:

```
// do not forget adding using System.Linq;
var filteredItems = items.OfType<IMyType>();
var values = new List<IMyType>(filteredItems);
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.
>   The OfType(IEnumerable) method returns only those elements in
>   source that can be cast to type TResult

Comment: `OfType<T>` is unnecessary in `foreach` loops if you specify the type explicitly instead of declaring the current item as `var`. Also, as far as I know, the `List<T>` constructor has an overload which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`. Even if not, you could just write `var values = items.OfType<MyType>().ToList()`.

Comment: @Tobias: obviously foreach is not required since `OfType()` will process all the items itself

Comment: Indeed. But _if_ you want to use a foreach, you _can_ filter the items by type just by specifying the item type explicitly ;)

Comment: No, you can not. You'll got an InvalidCastException

Answer (score 8):

C# has an [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator.

For example:

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
 if(item is string)
 {
   //Do something with the string.
 }
}
```

Comment: Explicit usage of `is` isn't necessary if you just type `foreach(string item in collection){...}`.

Comment: No, you can not. You'll got an InvalidCastException if anything other than string iterated

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator:

```
if(cell is MyType)
{
  // can work
}
```

`is`:

> Checks if an object is compatible with a given type.

Comment: Sadly `!cell is MyType` doesnt work, you have to write it as `!(cell is MyType)`. Which is kinda odd imo

Comment: @TJHeuvel: In (very rare imo) cases it can be necessary to check if `!cell` is a certain type. Also it seems perfectly logical to me (possibly because of common spacing rules and expression part length) that `!cell is Type` is equal to `(!cell) is Type` rather than `!(cell is Type)`.